# SVN Reorganization

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svnadmin

I know this question has been asked a few times, which I've found answers for on here and tried, but I can't get this to work, so looking some help.

Using VisualSVN Server 2.5.8 on Windows.

I originally set up a repository structure as follows:

[image: svnrepos]

This translates to `D:\SVN Repositories\`  so that each repository is in it's own folder
[image: directories]

I've started to finally realize that this is not very organized, as I'm up to 34 repos/folders, and I'd like to try and clean it up, something like this:

[image: svn3]

Using previous questions on here, I learned about SVNADMIN dump, and load.  So as a test, I tried the following:

```
svnadmin dump "D:\SVN Repositories\AndroidDebtDestroyer" > D:\Dump1.dump
```

I then tried to load this in to the new directory, using the following:

```
svnadmin load "D:\SVN Repositories\Android\AndroidDebtDestroyer" < D:\Dump1.dump
```

This didn't work, giving me an error:

> svnadmin: E720003: Can't open file 'D:\SVN
>   Repositories\Android\AndroidDebtDestroyer\format': The system cannot
>   find the path specified.

I've tried adding the --parent-dir command as well, but this also didn't work.

Unfortunately dragging does not work in VisualSVN Manager, and I can't just drag and drop repos into the new folders, so I'm sorta at a lose as to how to do this?  Can TortoiseSVN do this?  I'm not savvy with the commandline for svn

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to doing `svnadmin load` you must create the repository.

`svnadmin create "D:\SVN Repositories\Android\AndroidDebtDestroyer"`

I've not used visual svn server, I'm sorry I cannot speak to how it works.

Though I must say I'd rather have the 30odd repositories at the top level than the nested approach.  I remember the names, but not the paths... and these are things one tends to type a lot.

Comment: Originally the 30+ TLR's (Top Level Repos) was a better idea, yeah, but I'm thinking as I work on more projects that it might be easier to group by type of project, namely, Android, PC tools, and Circuit Board designs.   I dont know if the length would matter match, as I use either Tortoise SVN or an SVN plugin in visual studio or eclipse to check in code/files, so I rarely need to remember a url (unless I'm giving it out to someone to work on something.

Edit:  NVM.  you're right.   This is too much work to go and change all the repos over one by one.   Accepting this answer.

Comment: How many repositories you can handle from an administrative point of view depends on how good your scripting skills are.  The main advantage of more repositories over monolithic repositories are in the backup phase.  You can script so that svnadmin hotcopy backups only happen on repositories that have changed in the last N days.  Which might mean only needing to backup 10% of your repositories each night instead of all of them.